# Проверка целостности S19(SREC) файла C++

Tags: c++

У меня есть файл прошивки для контроллера в формате S19 (SREC). Как я понял внутри файла есть чексуммы. Есть ли какой-нибудь стандартный способ проверки файла на C++? Может функция из распротраненной библиотеки?

Comment: Из распространенных - скорее всего нет. Разбирайтесь с форматом файла и пишите свою реализацию проверки.

Comment: Спасибо, так в итоге и пришлось сделать.